# c++ pass array by value or pointer to function syntax

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference

Could somebody explain the difference between these two function declarations below please? As far I know, `aDecay()` takes a pointer as an argument and if you have an integer `int a[5]` you can call `aDecay(a)` or `aDecay(&a[0]` because an array decays to a pointer.

Now if I want to call `pDecay()` I have to use `pDecay(&a)`.

How does pDecay force you to use the `&`.

```
void aDecay(int *p)
void pDecay(int (*p)[7])
```

Answer (score 0):

With plain `a` (or its equal `&a[0]`) you have a pointer to a *single element* in the array. A single element is of type `int`, so a pointer to it must be `int*`.

If you have a pointer to the actual array, like you get with `&a`, you no longer have a pointer to a single `int` element but to the whole array. The type of the array is `int[5]`, and a pointer to it is `int(*)[5]`.

Also note that in *neither* case you pass the *array* by value. You pass a *pointer* by value.

Comment: That is very clear (and obvious now). Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a pointer to function syntax, it's a pointer to array syntax.

In the first example `p` is a pointer to an array of integers. `p[i]` is a single `int`. It cannot be indexed any further.

In the second example `p` is a pointer to an array of seven integer arrays. `p[i]` is an array which can be indexed further, i.e. `p[i][0]` is valid.

Here is an example of using the second approach:

```
void fill_data(int (*p)[7], size_t n) {
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i != n ; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0 ; j != 7 ; j++) {
            p[i][j] = (int)(7*i+j);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int data[10][7];
    fill_data(data, 10);
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/mmWwvy)

Answer (score 0):

`aDecay` takes a pointer to an `int`.
An array of `int` can decay to a pointer to the array's first element.

`pDecay` takes a pointer to an array of seven `int`s.
An array does not implicitly convert into a pointer to itself.

Answer (score 0):

Passing `p` will convert the array `p` to a pointer instead of keeping it as an array (this is called array decay, because the array decays to a pointer).

Passing `&p` will not convert `p` to a pointer, because it will convert the pointer *to* `p` to a generic pointer, which is not a big deal because it is actually a pointer.

Why we don't want to convert `p` to a pointer is because arrays are not *just* pointers. If you think that arrays are just pointers, try to compare `sizeof(myArray)` with `sizeof(myPointer)`. An array embeds also its size, not only the pointer to the first element.

Answer (score 0):

> How does `pDecay` force you to use the `&`.

Because an array doesn't decay to just any pointer. It specifically decays to pointer to first element. The type of pointer to first element of an array of `int` (i.e. `int[n]`) is: pointer to `int` (i.e. `int*`).

The argument of `pDecay` is `int (*p)[7]` which is a pointer to an array of 7 `int`. An `int*` is not implicitly convertible to `(int (*p)[7]`; they are separate, incompatible types. Note that `pDecay(&a)` won't work either because the type of `&a` is `(int (*p)[5]` which is also a different type than `(int (*p)[7]`.

---

`pDecay` doesn't force you to use `&` in general.  You could pass an array of arrays, which would then decay to a pointer to first array, which is what `pDecay` accepts:

```
int arr[n][7];
pDecay(arr);
```

---

> Could somebody explain the difference between these two function declarations below please?

`int*` is a pointer to an `int` object. `int (*p)[7]` is a pointer to an `int[7]` object i.e. an array of 7 `int`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a misconception in the question: if `a` is an array, `a` is always a pointer to that array, i.e. you do `pDecay(a)` - NOT `pDecay(&a)`. Now, `[ ]` is a dereferencing operation, so if you say `a[5]` - you dereference a pointer to `a` + 5 * `bytes in memory occupied by the array's unit`. Accordingly, `a` and `&a[0]` is exactly the same. `a[5]` and `&(a + 5)` is the same.

Answering your question, `aDecay(int *p)` takes a pointer to integer - nothing asks for an array here. `int (*p)[7]` is an array of 7 integers and compiler will check that's the case.